# MS Access: How to add multiple rows to table within 1 query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to create tables for temporary use in my database, each of them should have many rows (from 500 to 1200) that consist of two columns: id and bool element.

Is there any way to create a query that will insert such number of rows into table? Or is it possible to write a query that adds one row and write Visual Basic macros that will call the query a specified number of times?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest the VBA route, since you can use a `Loop`. What's the data look like?

Comment: Is *id* an autonumber field?

Comment: @Invent-Animate, you mean data relationship or what?

Comment: @HansUp, yes, it's autonumbered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you need with a fairly simple VBA procedure.

For example, to load 1000 rows into my *"Table3"* with False stored in the field named *"bool_field"*, I can call the procedure below like this ...

```vb
AddRows "Table3", "bool_field", False, 1000
```

That table's other field is AutoNumber type, so the db engine takes care of its value.

```vb
Public Sub AddRows(ByVal pTable As String, _
        ByVal pField As String, _
        ByVal pValue As Variant, _
        ByVal pHowMany As Long)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(pTable, , dbAppendOnly)
    With rs
        For i = 1 To pHowMany
            .AddNew
            .Fields(pField).Value = pValue
            .Update
        Next
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you prefer a query-based approach, you could execute an `INSERT` as many times as required within the `For i = 1 To pHowMany` section.

Comment: It doesn't work. 
[Screenshot of error message](http://s13.postimg.org/gsz8k4k3b/185.png)

How can I execute querry in procedure? Can you write a code?

Comment: The error message is Access complaining that you didn't supply a valid table name.  That problem will not be solved by changing the code to execute a query.  You would still need a valid table name.

Comment: You must supply the table name as a string.  Without the quotes around the table name in my example ... `AddRows Table3, "bool_field", False, 1000` ... Access gives me the exact same error message you reported.